# widget / template code for +1, Like, Follow on Twitter etc

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-media, google-plus-one

I am trying to setup a website for this design studio and need to put in a widget which would allow people to "Like, +1, follow on twitter" etc. I have been writing code for some years now, but I am relatively new to web development.

I was wondering if a widget or some online tool exists that would let me generate html/script code for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) is what you're looking for.